# Search within 2 arrays output matches in different color

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays of random numbers I need to search within the second array for number from the first array and mark them as matches by changing the colors of them with css if they match. Think of it like a lottery number checker.

I have done it in a long drawn out manner but I am wondering if there is a way to shorten the coding up.

```
    $white_balls = range(1, 70);
    shuffle($white_balls);
    $white_balls = array_slice($white_balls, 0, 5);

    $five_ball = range(1, 70);
    shuffle($five_ball);
    $five_ball = array_slice($five_ball, 0, 5);

    if(in_array($five_ball[0], $white_balls)) {
        echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$five_ball[0].'</span>, ';
    }else { echo $five_ball[0].", ";
        }   
    if(in_array($five_ball[1], $white_balls)) {
         echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$five_ball[1].'</span>, ';
    }else { echo $five_ball[1].", ";
        }
    if(in_array($five_ball[2], $white_balls)) {
        echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$five_ball[2].'</span>, ';
    }else { echo $five_ball[2].", ";
            }
    if(in_array($five_ball[3], $white_balls)) {
        echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$five_ball[3].'</span>, ';
    }else { echo $five_ball[3].", ";
        }
    if(in_array($five_ball[4], $white_balls)) {
        echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$five_ball[4].'</span>, ';
    }else { echo $five_ball[4]." - ";
        }
```

Comment: One option to shorten your code is to [map over](https://eval.in/907896) your choices instead repeated if/else statements - or you could use `foreach`

Comment: You should post this at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead

Comment: @DarraghEnright While your code works for the most part it is highlighting some numbers that are not in the list of "winning numbers". Unfortunately I don't understand your code well enough to figure out why. I guess it is research time.... I'll get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function draw_balls($draw_count, $total_balls) {
    $balls = range(1, $total_balls);
    shuffle($balls);

    return array_slice($balls, 0, $draw_count);
}

$one = draw_balls(5, 10);
$two = draw_balls(5, 10);

foreach($two as $num)
    $out[] = in_array($num, $one)
        ? '<span style="color:red;">' . $num . '</span>'
        : $num;

print implode(', ', $out);
```

Further:

```
$winning_balls = array_intersect($two, $one);

printf('Summary: %d out of %d balls are winners.',
    count($winning_balls),
    count($two)
);
```